# calling php script from within another one

Tags: exec, shell-exec

i'm trying to automate a process whereby i have a controlling script that reads through a SQL table for active scripts to process.

this controlling script calls several php functions to write log entries, etc to a sql table.  the script will also need to call an external php script to process data (name of the script to process the data is held in the sql table)

i've tried using both exec and shell_exec and it appears to just hang when trying to call the second php script.

i'm running windows 7 but ultimately this will be deployed on a Windows Server 2008R2

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can include your another script and call his functions ;)

```
include 'myAnotherScript.php';
```